# org.json.simple.jsonObject throws noclassdeffounderror proguard maven

Tags: java, android, maven, proguard, noclassdeffounderror

I have android library which is built using maven and proguard. I am not able to solve the error in it which is as below.

> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.json.simple.JSONObject

and my pom file has option to add that library and

```
                 <inclusions>
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
                  </inclusions>
                 <options> 
                       <option>-keep class org.json.** {*;}</option>
                       <option>-keepnames class org.json.** {*;}</option>  
                  </options>
```

Still I am getting NoClassDefFoundError at runtime. please Help me.

Comment: have you added any library into your application?

Comment: @ Kruti It may because of duplicate packages. As error triggers that android had inbuilt json library with same package name so it is conflict.If you still  want to use your own built library just change the package name of your library.

Comment: I reverified.. no duplicate libraries or packages... :(..

Comment: Birajjj how r u... long time... thanks for replying buddy ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have found answer :

I added Inclusion tag for json-simple as well.. so proguard doesnt strip out that library when optimizing. and works fine now :D

```
                        <inclusion>
                            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
                            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
                            <library>true</library>
                        </inclusion>
```

Thanks